# A supplementary construction

Tags: geometry

Let $ ABC $ an acute triangle and $O$ is the middle  of $[BC] $ .

Let $\mathcal {C} $ the circle with center in $O $ and radius $OA $.

Let $AB\cap \mathcal{C}=\lbrace D \rbrace$  and $AC\cap \mathcal {C} =\lbrace E\rbrace $.

If $ M $ is the intersections of the tangents to the circle $\mathcal {C} $ in $D $ respectively $E $, and $P $ is the middle  of $AM $ show that $PB=PC $.

My ideas: First time I tried to make an inversion with respect to the circle $\mathcal {C} $.

The second time I considered $AO\cap \mathcal {C}=\lbrace Z\rbrace $ and I draw $XY $ trough $Z $ s.t. $XY||BC $ and $X\in AB $, $Y\in AC $.

$B $ is the middle of $AX $, $C $ is the middle of $AY $.

Now I have to show that $MX=MY $. I am stuck.

.[image]

Comment: This is the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2779788, isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $OB=OC $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779788/show-that-ob-oc)